# not able to upload photo after upgradation of cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am developing an app for android using phonegap in which i am using cordova 3.5.1.jar,required plugins and cordova 3.5.1js file after upgradation from 2.9.0 cordova.To upload camera image and video i am using  below function.here i am not able to upload image to to server .When i debugged it i came to know that window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI() function is not getting executing and in filetransfer plugin it executing errorcallback function on fail.Whats the error in code please guide me to solve this issue.

filetransfer.js in plugin

```
var self = this;
var win = function(result) {
    if (typeof result.lengthComputable != "undefined") {
        if (self.onprogress) {
            self.onprogress(newProgressEvent(result));
        }
    } else {
        successCallback && successCallback(result);
    }
};
exec(win, fail, 'FileTransfer', 'upload', [filePath, server, fileKey,    fileName, mimeType, params, trustAllHosts, chunkedMode, headers, this._id, httpMethod]);
};



var fail = errorCallback && function(e) {
    var error = new FileTransferError(e.code, e.source, e.target, e.http_status, e.body);
//alert("error");
    errorCallback(error);
};
```

index.html

```
 function uploadimage(resid) {
        var fileName;
        for(var i=0;i<Locphotos.length;i++)
         {
            if (!Locphotos[i]) {

            return;
        }
             fileName= Locphotos[i];
        /*  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(Locphotos[i], function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
            fileName = fileObj.fullPath;});
        });  */

        server = "http://mangitna/service.asmx?op=UploadFile";
        if (server) {
            // Specify transfer options
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "file";
            options.fileName = resid+"-A-" + fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";
            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            options.headers = {
            Connection: "close"
            };

            var ftLocphotos = new FileTransfer();

            ftLocphotos.upload(fileName, server, function (r) {

            }, function (error) {

            }, options);
        }
        }
    }
```

UPDATED:

after commenting resolveLocalFileSystemURL function.

Comment: a lot of things changed since phonegap 2.9, you should create a new empty project with latest cordova using the CLI, put your code on the www folder and add the platforms and plugins needed

Comment: @ jcesarmobile i have done it,but no use.can u tell me why resolveLocalFileSystemURI() is not working here

Comment: It's resolveLocalFileSystemURL, not resolveLocalFileSystemURI

Comment: @jcesarmobile no after replacing also its not working

Comment: now you have to debug the app to find the problem. Start by looking into the logcat to see if there are any javascript error showing

Comment: @jcesarmobile i made it working by commenting resolveLocalFileSystemURL function and passing location[i] to filename now its working.but i am still not able to understand why its doesnt get upload if that function is added.

Comment: put some console.log or alert on the success and the error callbacks